# How to copy on GPU a vector-of-vector-pointer-memory-allocated in OpenACC

Tags: c++, stdvector, openacc

I'm trying to copy on GPU a vector of vector array.

I tried with OpenACC  copyin clause. The copyin clause does not copie all underlying data of my array. When I try to access to underlying vector data, I get an "illegal adress access" error at runtime.

```
vector<int32_t> *k1p = new vector<int32_t>[bin_num];
for (int i = 0; i < bin_mum; i++) {
  //......
  k1p[i].push_back(i);
}
#pragma acc kernels loop independent copyin(k1p[0:bin_num])
for (int i = 0; i < bin_mum; i++) {
  //........
  for (vector<int32_t>::const_iterator i2_it=k1p[i].begin(); i2_it!=k1p[i].end(); i2_it++) {
    //.......
  }
  //..........
}
```

I want to access to element of underlying vector k1p[i], but actually this code compile with pgi compiler, but when I run this code, I get

> call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution

Answer (score 1):

OpenACC data clauses only perform shallow copies of an object.  Since a "vector" is a collection of three pointers, this means that putting the vector in a copyin clause will only copy the pointers, not the data it's pointing to.

Assuming you're using PGI, the easiest thing to do is use CUDA Unified Memory (i.e. add the flag "-ta=tesla:managed"), and have the CUDA runtime manage the data movement for you.

Otherwise, you need to perform a manual deep copy of the vector.  This can be a bit tricky, especially with vectors, so let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Mat Colgrove. Please, I need an example.

Answer (score 1):

Again, I strongly advise using CUDA Unified Memory (managed) when using C++ vectors on the device.  Vectors are a container type with three private pointers.  Given an OpenACC copy or update does a shallow copy, when putting a vector in a data region you'll be copying the pointers, not the data they point to.  Worse, since the pointers are private, they can't be updated with a device pointer.

Instead, you'll need to create an array of temp pointers to shadow the vector array's data and then use this temp variable on the device.  Something like the following:

```
% cat vector.data.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int bin_num = 1024;
   long sum = 0;

   vector<int32_t> *k1p = new vector<int32_t>[bin_num];
   for (int i = 0; i < bin_num; i++) {
       k1p[i].push_back(i);
   }

   int32_t ** temp = new int32_t*[bin_num];
   int * sizes = new int[bin_num];
   #pragma acc enter data create(temp[0:bin_num][0:0])
   for (int i = 0; i < bin_num; i++) {
      int sze = k1p[i].size();
      sizes[i] = sze;
      temp[i] = k1p[i].data();
      #pragma acc enter data copyin(temp[i:1][:sze])
   }
   #pragma acc enter data copyin(sizes[:bin_num])

  #pragma acc parallel loop gang vector reduction(+:sum) present(temp,sizes)
  for (int i = 0; i < bin_num; i++) {
     for (int j=0; j< sizes[i]; ++j) {
         sum += temp[i][j];
     }
  }
  cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
  #pragma acc exit data delete(sizes)
  #pragma acc exit data delete(temp)
  delete [] sizes;
  delete [] k1p;
}

% pgc++ vector.data.cpp --c++11 -ta=tesla  -V18.10
% a.out
Sum: 523776
```

When using managed memory, the addresses are in a unified memory space which is accessible to both the host and device.  Hence when you access "begin" and "end", the addresses they return on the device are valid.  For example:

```
% cat vector.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   const int bin_num = 1024;
   long sum = 0;
   vector<int32_t>::const_iterator i2_it;

   vector<int32_t> *k1p = new vector<int32_t>[bin_num];
   for (int i = 0; i < bin_num; i++) {
       k1p[i].push_back(i);
   }

#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:sum) private(i2_it)
  for (int i = 0; i < bin_num; i++) {
    for (i2_it=k1p[i].begin(); i2_it!=k1p[i].end(); i2_it++) {
         sum += *i2_it;
     }
  }
  cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}

% pgc++ vector.cpp --c++11 -ta=tesla:managed -V18.10
% a.out
Sum: 523776
```

Another alternative is to write you're own vector like class.  I wrote a basic example of how to do this as part of Chapter 5 of [Parallel Programming with OpenACC](https://www.elsevier.com/books/parallel-programming-with-openacc/farber/978-0-12-410397-9).  Code samples can be found at https://github.com/rmfarber/ParallelProgrammingWithOpenACC